# Flink stop job API returns "308 Permanent Redirect"

Tags: apache-flink

I am following the [Flink REST API doc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/rest_api.html#jobs-jobid-1) to use `PATCH /jobs/:jobid?mode=stop` to stop a job, but the I got HTTP response "308 Permanent Redirect". The job is definitely running. I don't know what the error means and how I should stop the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/rest_api.html#jobs-jobid-1):

mode (optional): String value that specifies the termination mode. The only supported value is: "cancel".

it should be "cancel", not "stop".

Comment: Seems the doc has been fixed. Thanks!